# Render data into a template in golang

Tags: go, go-html-template

I want to render 2 different data(startup, event in this case) at the same time into html using golangs' html/template.

```
var startupData []model.StartupModel
err = startupCollection.Find(nil).Sort("-timestamp").All(&startupData )

var eventData []model.EventModel
err = eventCollection.Find(nil).Sort("-timestamp").All(&eventData )
```

How can I combine both startupData and EventData into a variable so that I can render as the following ?

```
    t.Execute(w, result) // result is eventData + startupData
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a struct and pass to `Execute` function

```
...
result := struct {
        StartupData []model.StartupModel
        EventData []model.EventModel
    }{
        StartupData : startupData,
        EventData : eventData,
    }
t.Execute(w, result)
```